# Are there any donation limits or cooldowns of the clan chest?

Tags: clash-royale

Are there daily donation limitations or cool downs for contributing to the clan chest?

What I know:

> - I know [how much gold and how many/what types of cards](http://clashroyale.wikia.com/wiki/Clan_Chest) are given with each chest level.
> - I know you have to contribute at least one crown during the event to receive the rewards.
> - I know that no crowns other than those earned in **ladder play** count towards the total.
> - I know that your arena level directly impacts that cards you can acquire.
> - I am aware that joining/leaving a clan mid event disqualifies you from receiving any rewards until the clan resets.
> - I am also aware that joining mid event still allows you to help even though you won't receive rewards.
> - It would take a Clan of 50 earning 9.29 crowns per day for the 7
>     days to  reach the level 10 (or max) clan chest at 3,250 crowns.

Is there anything else I am missing? Or any advice on how to meet the bench mark?

Comment: Where are these terms from? "Guild" instead of "Clan", and in other post "Mana" instead of "Elixir".

Comment: Aye, they are from a different game. XD - I was in a guild in WoW for a decade. Sometimes the terminology comes back in. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can contribute an infinte amount of Crowns to your Clan Chest, until it reaches Tier 10.** But there is no need to rush, there is a whole week at your disposal.

Comment: Seconding on the no rush, our clan has finished both quickly and it does not make the next appear any sooner.

Comment: Now that we have had 2 cycles I can update. There is no rush...  
***BUT*** - If your clan reaches level 10 Clan Chest  
 - Before you contribute a crown... even on day 1  
 - You've dropped trophies to help but haven't reached your normal   arena
***You will not/will*** Receive any cards/receive the cards from your current arena.

Coordination can be key.

Answer (score 0):

I played around 100 games for the Clan Chest yesterday, and the only limitation was the classic daily victory coin reward limit (amount varies by arena). Even after the game said I can't get any victory rewards, I was able to win Crowns for the Clan Chest.

Also, you do not "donate" Crowns, your clan chest's crown counter automatically gets increased by the amount of towers you destroy when you finish a game (to reword, it's totally automatic, and you lose nothing for contributing).

As pythonmaster stated, the only limit is when the chest is filled. You simply can't add more crowns at that state.

Comment: The limit is when you get the max chest